# QOpenGLWidget update() doesn't render scene when multisampling enabled

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I'm trying to use anti-aliasing to get shaper edges in my scene. However, when I enable multisampling and I call QOpenGLWidget::update() the scene doesn't update. Although if I click on the scene then an anti-aliased scene is rendered. If I comment out the one line setting the number of samples used then an aliased scene is rendered as normal when calling update.

I set the default surface format in main.cpp I'm using CoreProfile 4.3 with samples set to 4.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include "widgets/mainwindow.h"

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    auto format = QSurfaceFormat();
    format.setVersion(4,3);
    //If I comment out this line everything works great but with jagged edges 
    format.setSamples(4);
    format.setProfile(QSurfaceFormat::CoreProfile);
    QSurfaceFormat::setDefaultFormat(format);
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    MainWindow w;
    w.show();
    w.resize(1200, 800);
    return a.exec();
}
```

In my viewer.cpp which inherits from QOpenGLWidget I enable GL_MULTISAMPLE

```
   QOpenGLFunctions *f = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions();

    f->glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    f->glEnable(GL_MULTISAMPLE);
```

An example (there are many more) that doesn't render when I call update when using multisampling is when I load in a new mesh.

```
auto ViewerWidget::importMesh(QString filename) -> void
{
    mesh = new Mesh(filename);
    initializeGL();
    update();

}
```

However, when I click on the screen then the scene does update. My mouse movement events are below and don't do anything special compared to my mesh import method.

```
void ViewerWidget::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
        m_rotationTrackball.push(pixelPosToViewPos(event->pos()), m_scaleTrackball.rotation().conjugate());
    }
    update();
}

void ViewerWidget::mouseReleaseEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton) {
        m_rotationTrackball.release(pixelPosToViewPos(event->pos()), m_scaleTrackball.rotation().conjugate());
    }
    update();
}

void ViewerWidget::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    if (event->buttons() & Qt::LeftButton)
    {
        m_rotationTrackball.move(pixelPosToViewPos(event->pos()), m_scaleTrackball.rotation().conjugate());
    }
    else
    {
        m_rotationTrackball.release(pixelPosToViewPos(event->pos()), m_scaleTrackball.rotation().conjugate());
    }
    update();
}
```

Any suggestions on how to solve this would be appreciated! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which platform / Qt version? There's a number of bugs related to MSAA, you might want to look on the bugtracker...

Comment: I'm using OSX 10.10.5 and Qt 5.4.0

Comment: Can you try 5.5.0 or 5.5.1? Maybe it's already fixed.

Comment: I've switched to 5.5.0 and it is already fixed - thanks.